# how to find vertices of a rectangular polygon drawn as a line with 2 end points and a width

Tags: graphics, polygon, vertices

A line specified by 2 end points and a width can be converted to a rectangular polygon with 4 vertices and then displayed using a scan line method. Develop an efficient algorithm  for computing the 4 vertices needed to define such a rectangle using line end points and line width.

Comment: This looks like [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). [:-)](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)